# java.lang.IllegalAccessError on launch of react native activity in release mode

Tags: react-native

I have added one React Native screen to my existing android project.

Copying the proguard settings related to react native from 
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/local-cli/generator-android/templates/src/app/proguard-rules.pro WORKS.

However I want to enable obfuscation for my project and hence commented out the line -dontobfuscate

After this, when I deploy the release build in my nexus device, I get this error :
    `E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
    Process: com.sampleapp, PID: 2463
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
       at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Method 'void android.support.v4.net.ConnectivityManagerCompat.<init>()' is inaccessible to class 'com.facebook.react.modules.netinfo.NetInfoModule' (declaration of 'com.facebook.react.modules.netinfo.NetInfoModule' appears in /data/app/com.sampleapp-1/base.apk)
       at com.facebook.react.modules.netinfo.NetInfoModule.<init>(NetInfoModule.java:55)
       at com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage.createNativeModules(MainReactPackage.java:67)
       at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerImpl.processPackage(ReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:793)
       at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerImpl.createReactContext(ReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:730)
       at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerImpl$ReactContextInitAsyncTask.doInBackground(ReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:5091)
       at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerImpl$ReactContextInitAsyncTask.doInBackground(ReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:169)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)`

This link does mention obfuscation isn't supported in React-Native: 
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7530

I want to obfuscate existing app code.

Comment: can you please post top level build.gradle file code.